# IEnumerable not accepting my class as a type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, types, ienumerable

I'm trying to cast a dynamic set of values so that I can use a lambda expression to query them, but I keep getting errors when casting the collection as `IEnumerable`:

`(IEnumerable<MyClass>ViewBag.MyClassList)`

causes the errors

`Using the generic type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> requires 1 type arguments`

and

`MyClass is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context`

This literally makes zero sense. `IEnumerable` wants a type, but using a type `is not valid in the given context`.

Halp?

Comment: Could be a matter of brackets. Try `((IEnumerable<MyClass>) ViewBag.MyClassList)`

Comment: Then you should show some relevant code so we can help you with that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets should do the trick:

`((IEnumerable<MyClass>) ViewBag.MyClassList)`

Answer (score 0):

Not much information there for context.

`ViewBag.MyClassList as IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Might be an extension method or two too

`ViewBag.MyClassList.ConvertAll<MyClass>()`

`ViewBag.MyClassList.ToList<MyClass>()`

but other than that, Jeroen has the "CAST" approach and parenthesis usage